# Firebase auth send verification link after Sign Up / Registration

Tags: reactjs, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I'am using Fireabse auth with react js and firebase SDK.

So I'm able to register / login and send a verification link after login, but I need to send the verification email after sign up, the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method return a user object (not like the old sdk version you can use that user result to send email).

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
console.log(user.uid)
}
```

Any help please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `user` in the callback is a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) object.  You can get a User object with `user.user`, and you can use that object to send the email with [user.user.sendEmailVerification()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendemailverification).